# How to store one part of a return in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, function, return

Alright. So, I have a function that I'm testing out. It has two returns. Here is the code:

```
x = 5
y = 7
def test(w, z):
    if w == 5 and z == 7:
        print("good!")
        w = 6
        z = 12
    return(w, z)

test(x, y)
```

Alright so, there's my test function. It takes 'x' and 'y' and it does some stuff with them, and then it changes them if both are equal to the numbers.

However, I might want to keep that information that 'w' became 6 and 'z' became 12. In this case, I want 'w's value to equal 'x's. Likewise with 'y' and 'z'.

Unfortunately, when I try what I had already learned from stackOverflow:

```
x = test(x, y)
print(x)
```

I would get `(6, 12)`. How can I make it so that 'x' gets 'w's value and 'y' gets 'z's value?

Comment: did you mean `x, y = test(x, y)` ?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
x,y = test(x, y)
```